# Force closing a thread using openMP in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I want to close a thread in openMP after running a certain amount of time. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to kill a spinning thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978668/is-it-possible-to-kill-a-spinning-thread)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it's not a duplicate of that. He is asking about openmp, not explicit threads.

Comment: @Tudor And what is the difference between an OpenMP thread and a normal thread? A thread is a thread is a thread, how it was started shouldn't matter.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: there is a big difference with respect to rushafi's question: OpenMP threads are managed and cannot be handled from the outside. You cannot perform join/suspend/abort on them, nor can you start them explicitly. Therefore, if the question would have been "how do I stop an explicit thread?" the possible answer could have been "call abort". But since this is about openmp the same rules do not apply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenMP threads cannot be killed forcefully from the outside. They do not have a handle that you can use to perform operations like join, interrupt, abort, etc.

In fact, OpenMP is not even designed for this. It's better to just let the runtime handle the threads and use explicit threads if you need to do something special.

Comment: Can you suggest a cross platform threading library for C++ in which I can force close a thread after an amount of time?

Comment: Perhaps you could use pthreads. Windows does not support them natively but there are implementations like this one: http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/

Answer (score 2):

Killing of threads is possible [**outside parallel**], not using openmp API but through `pthread_cancel()`.

**NOTE** : Killing openmp thread within `parallel` section is not recommended as Openmp barrier at the end of `for` loop will be expecting all threads to hit barrier. If one thread doesn't report/hit, then it will be infinite hang. Also, user may have to take care of thread/memory cleanup upon explicit killing.

```
 pthread_t pt;
 #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(3) firstprivate(i)
 for(n=0; n<10; ++n)
 {
        tid = gettid();
        pt = pthread_self();
        printf("i=%d -  %d - thread : %d :: TID=%d\n",i++, n, omp_get_thread_num(), gettid());
 }
printf("TID : %d - PT=%d\n", tid, pt);
pthread_cancel(pt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if one can do this for a specific thread, but you can achieve something similar with a [trick](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#CancellingOfThreadsAndBreakingOutOfLoops). What you basically do, you set a flag and flush that to the running threads when the time is up. Check the link for more details about it.